# How to fix Invalid Parameter To

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to validate codes sent using Twilio. Currently the function to send the verification code works great, but the function to verify the code is not working as expected.

I've tried replace the parameter `to` with `To`, `verificationSid`, `VerificationSid` and none of them seem to work as expected.

```js
exports.validateVerificationCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var number = req.body.number;
  var code = req.body.code;
  twilio.verify.services('VA{MY_SERVICE_ID}').verificationChecks.create({
    to: number, 
    code: code
  }).then((validation_check) => {
    res.status(200).json(validation_check);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json(err);
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

I expect the function to run as shown in the API docs, but my firebase console keeps showing me

> "[Error: Invalid parameter: To]
>     status: 400" and when I replace 'to' with 'To', it gives me the following error "[Error: Either a 'To' number or 'VerificationSid' must be specified]
>     status: 400".

Comment: Are you sure that number is defined ?

Comment: yes, number is defined, also is code.

Comment: I debugged and found out that although my client was sending the number with "+", the backend received the number without "+". I had to manually add "+" to the number in backend and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things, did you check to see if the to number: is in E.164 format, https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164 and that you are using a more current version of the Twilio Node SDK Helper Library? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/CHANGES.md.

My working code look very similar, so I feel it is one of the two issues above (I tested with Twilio Node Helper Library 3.31.1).

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

const client = context.getTwilioClient();   
const code = event.code;
let phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber;

client.verify.services('VA1exxxxxxbc6e02520c585xxxxxxxxxx')
         .verificationChecks
         .create({to: phoneNumber, code: code})
         .then(verification_check => {
             console.log(`***VERIFICATION STATUS***: ${verification_check.status}`);
            //  Object.keys(verification_check).forEach(thisKey => console.log(`${thisKey}: ${verification_check[thisKey]}`));
             callback(null, `${verification_check.status}`);
         })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              callback();
          });
         };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, one question, if the number isn’t formatted correctly, wouldn’t it give a different error? Also, I installed the ‘npm install twilio’ only yesterday, but I’ll check the version just to be sure. But I even hardcoded the number ‘+1xxxxxxxxxx’ and it still have invalid parameter error.

Comment: I remember I had an issue with the to: not being in E.164 format but don't remember the error. When I ran it today, without an E.164 formatted to, I got:



{ [Error: Either a 'To' number or 'VerificationSid' must be specified]
  status: 400,
  message: 'Either a \'To\' number or \'VerificationSid\' must be specified',
  code: 400,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/400',
  detail: undefined }